# The Stepdown Rule in Clean Code

Tags: coding-style, coffeescript, function-declaration

There is something about the *Stepdown Rule* (high level function at top and low level next) in clean code (Chapter 3, One Level of Abstraction per Function ). 
   What should I do when I use coffeescript since there is no function declarations in coffeescript.

**example:**

```
 seeAMovie = ()->
     BuyTheTicket()
     watch()

 BuyTheTicket = ()->
     //some thing

 watch = () ->
     //some thing
```

I want to do like this.

Comment: `f = (x) -> ...` counts as a function declaration, doesn't it? And you might want to be a bit more explicit about what this *Stepdown Rule* says.

Comment: Stepdown Rule: "We want every function to be followed by those at the next level of abstraction". It mean that we may use a next level function which have not been declared .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CoffeeScript doesn't really affect this rule.  The rule doesn't have anything to do with declarations, but even if it did, CoffeeScript *does* have declarations anyway.  As @muistooshort said, here's a CoffeeScript function declaration:

```
functionName = (arg1, arg2) -> 
  functionBodyLine1
  functionBodyLine2
```

Those parenthesis are optional in the declaration if there are no arguments. Here's an example of the Step-Down Rule in CoffeeScript in action:

```
highLevel = ->
  doSomethingAlmostAsHighLevel1()
  doSomethingAlmostAsHighLevel2()

doSomethingAlmostAsHighLevel1 = ->
  doSomethingALittleLowerLevel1()

...
```

Note about your edit: That's perfectly fine and follows the Step-down rule.  What is wrong with your sample?

Not mentioned in the book, but Uncle Bob clarified to me that when two functions - at the same level of abstraction - use the same lower level function, they should be ordered like so:

```
highLevel1 = -> lowLevel()
highLevel2 = -> lowLevel()
lowLevel = -> ...
```

Comment: Ok, I think I have some misunderstanding of this part! Thank you